# JSON string validate with more than one class

Tags: java, json, validation, parsing, objectmapper

In my business flow I may have JSON strings with different formats.

For example:

```
String jsonSring = readValue();//this JSON String may contain Teacher object or Student Object
```

Currently i'm using this simple method to validate if the JSON is relative to a `Teacher` or `Student`:

```
try{
    Teacher teacher = om.readValue(jsonSring, Teacher.class);
}catch(Exception e){
    Student student = om.readValue(jsonSring, Student.class);
}
```

Any simplified method to validate the JSON content?

Comment: You mean something like: https://json-schema.org/

Comment: in this link are most of the methods that can help you
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: @flaimme im not looking to schema checking. I want to parse to two structure at same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Add a *Type* field:

Adding a field that specifies the object type is probably the easiest choice, but you must be able to change the objects in order to do that.

```
public Enum UserType { Teacher, Student, /* possibly other types */ }

public interface ISchoolMember 
{
    public string Name { get; }
    ..
    public UserType Type { get; }
}
```

Then once you have the JSON, you can parse it to JObject and read the Type field:

```
public ISchoolMember Deserialize(string jsonString)
{ 
    var o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    return (UserType)o["Type"] switch
    {
        UserType.Teacher => JsonConvert.Deserialize<Teacher>(jsonString),
        UserType.Student => JsonConvert.Deserialize<Student>(jsonString),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("...")
    };
}
```

---

**Solution 2**: Check for peculiar fields.

If it is not possible to add a new field, you can check if the parsed JObject contains fields that belong only to one of the two objects:

```
public void DeserializeAndDoStuff(string jsonString)
{ 
    var teacherOrStudent = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    if (teacherOrStudent["StudentId"] != null) // it is a student!
    {
        Student s = teacherOrStudent.ToObject<Student>();
        // ... do stuff with the student object
    } 
    else if (teacherOrStudent["TeacherId"] != null) // it is a teacher!
    {
        Teacher t = teacherOrStudent.ToObject<Teacher>();
        // ... do stuff with the teacher object
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The given object is neither a teacher or a student.");
    }
}
```

---

These two methods seem more verbose than the original way, but help moving away from an Exception-based programming (that is always unadvised, as handling exceptions is very costly in term of resources).

*p.s.

this implementation uses Newtonsoft.Json library, but I guess that other libraries have similar mechanisms.*

Comment: its not possible becouse Teacher and students calsses are already existing classes. I can't touch on it.

Comment: @Araf I updated the answer adding another possible solution.

Comment: It's ok, may have a chance to come the student or teacher id field comes as null.